# How to kill all active and inactive oracle sessions for user

Tags: oracle, session, stored-procedures, schema

I am trying the below script to kill all active and inactive oracle sessions for user at once but it doesn't work. The script executes successfully but does not kill sessions for user.

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'USER')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || r.sid 
      || ',' || r.serial# || '''';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What is the status of those sessions? The fact that you kill a session does not mean that it will disappear immediately. If the session has some transaction open, then it first rollbacks (it ca take long time) and then it will quit. So mine recommendation is to check column STATUS in V$session.

Comment: i checked the column status and its showing few active sessions. So it has not been killed ..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `KILL SESSION` command doesn't actually *kill* the session. It merely asks the session to kill itself. In some situations, like waiting for a reply from a remote database or rolling back transactions, the session will not kill itself immediately and will wait for the current operation to complete. In these cases the session will have a status of "**marked for kill**". It will then be killed as soon as possible.

Check the status to confirm:

```
SELECT sid, serial#, status, username FROM v$session;
```

You could also use **IMMEDIATE** clause:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#' IMMEDIATE;
```

The `IMMEDIATE` clause does not affect the work performed by the command, but it returns control back to the current session immediately, rather than waiting for confirmation of the kill. Have a look at [Killing Oracle Sessions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions).

**Update** If you want to kill all the sessions, you could just prepare a small script.

```
SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||sid||','||serial#||''' IMMEDIATE;' FROM v$session;
```

**Spool** the above to a `.sql` file and execute it, or, copy paste the output and run it.

Comment: Hello lalit what you are saying its true and i know the above sql coomands to check and kill session immediately. But its not the answer of my question. Lets say i have 20 session active and inactive. Then i cant simply want to write 20 alter statements to kill them. I want to kill them at once.

Comment: yes but cant we create loop or procedure to kill this sessions at once? I dont know in future there might be more than 20 sessions for my user.

Comment: @Rahul Never use PL/SQL when you could do it in pure SQL. Also, this is not something which you keep doing every now and then. And if you really want to do it very frequently, then as I added an update, just create a small script as I have shown above.

Comment: Hello lalit just a small question dont i need to specfiy user for which i am killing session in your query ?

Comment: You said all sessions, so I didn't add any filter. If you want to kill a specific user's session, then put `WHERE username = <username>` look at the other attributes of `v$session`. If it is a RAC, use `gv$session`.

Comment: To kill al sessions: `SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||sid||','||serial#||''';' FROM v$session;` and then copy results and execute. The author forgot to put some ' characters

Answer (score 24):

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (select sid,serial# from v$session where username='user')
  LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || r.sid  || ',' 
        || r.serial# || ''' immediate';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This should work - I just changed your script to add the `immediate` keyword. As the previous answers pointed out, the `kill session` only marks the sessions for killing; it does not do so immediately but later when convenient.

From your question, it seemed you are expecting to see the result immediately. So `immediate` keyword is used to force this.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight, i am new to this.Updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't obvious what you'd done differently.

Answer (score 10):

Execute this script:

```
SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||sid||','||serial#||''' IMMEDIATE;' 
FROM v$session 
where username='YOUR_USER';
```

It will printout sqls, which should be executed.

Answer (score 6):

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (select sid,serial# from v$session where username='user')
  LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || r.sid  || ',' || r.serial# || '''';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

> It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle 11g this may not work as you may receive an error like below

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00026: missing or invalid session ID
00026. 00000 -  "missing or invalid session ID"
*Cause:    Missing or invalid session ID string for ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION.
*Action:   Retry with a valid session ID.
```

To rectify this, use below code to identify the sessions

`SQL> select inst_id,sid,serial# from gv$session` or v$session

**NOTE** : **v$session do not have inst_id field**

and Kill them using

```
alter system kill session 'sid,serial,@inst_id' IMMEDIATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

inactive session the day before kill

```css
begin
    for i in (select * from v$session where status='INACTIVE' and (sysdate-PREV_EXEC_START)>1)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(q'{ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '}'||i.sid||q'[,]'  ||i.serial#||q'[']'||' IMMEDIATE');
    END LOOP;
end;
```