# Killing active and inactive sessions in oracledb

Tags: oracle, session, kill

I am trying to execute stored procedure package changes from sql developer console and oracle session hangs. For now I am killing the oracledb and launching it again

I checked stackoverflow regarding the issue and came across a similar question [How to kill all active and inactive oracle sessions for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201693/how-to-kill-all-active-and-inactive-oracle-sessions-for-user) which suggests the following queries to kill hanging sessions

```
SELECT sid, serial#, status FROM v$session;
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#' IMMEDIATE;
```

But on executing them I get

```
"table or view does not exist"
```

Can someone help me with queries to fetch all sessions and killing hanging sessions in oracledb ?

Comment: You're likely running this query with a user which does not have the grants to access v$session. If you can, you could try with a different user, otherwise you may need some help from your DBA

Comment: oh is it! I will check with my DBA

Comment: It's curious that you lack DB privs to see sessions currently active, yet you can bounce the database itself?? And the DBA doesn't come chasing after you??

Comment: That's why I am wondering whether it is a permission related issue. It is not because I am using the schema credentials which has permission to make changes to the database

Comment: @thatjeffsmith is there any other reason for the error ? it says table or view does not exist which is weird

Comment: @AarishRamesh that's the error you will get if you don't have SELECT privs on v$session - i find it odd you would not have that but would have privs on ALTER SYSTEM